# Can XCTestCases be grouped hierarchically?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xctest, xcuitest

I'm looking for a way (if it's even possible) to hierarchically group my `XCTestCase`s. I've been googling and the only somewhat similar thing I found is [Grouping Tests into Substeps with Activities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/activities_and_attachments/grouping_tests_into_substeps_with_activities?language=objc), which is not what I want (grouping individual tests and groups into other groups).

For example, here's what the thing I want to do looks like in other languages, e.g. Dart (but it's very similar with Jest in JavaScript land as well):

```dart
void main() {
  group('Top group', () {
    group('nested group 1', () {
      test('test case 1', () {});
      test('test case 2', () {});
      // ...
    });

    group('some other nested group', () { /* test cases here ... */ });
  });
}
```

The structure is detected by the tooling such as IDEs:

[image]

Is it possible to accomplish this with [`XCTestCase`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase)? Ideally the solution could be accomplished entirely at runtime, it could even involve some dark magic with Objective-C runtime, as long as it had a chance to work.

If it's not possible, I'd like to hear that as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With plain XCTest, no. But with the third-party library Quick, yes. https://github.com/Quick/Quick

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From what I see on Quick's website, the hierarchy is still flat when in the Xcode report viewer.

Comment: I was also thinking about creating XCTestSuite and XCTestCases dynamically with Objective-C runtime, using methods like XCTestSuite.addTest (which accepts an XCTest, and XCTestSuite is a subclass of XCTest, so I was thinking that it *may* be possible). Curious to hear what you think about it.

Comment: I'm afraid the XCTest reporter may still flatten things, but you never know until you try an experiment.